# Is there a way to create css sharp corners for button with border?

Tags: css, button

is there a way to create such button in css? The one with "blog" text. I tried adding a div into each corner, giving these divs borders and rotating them, but as you can see (the Anout Me btn) it is not the best solution as the corners don't fit accurately.

[image: button with sharp corners and border]
[image: attempt for the btn]

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: Does it have to be a single `<button>` element, or are you open to cluttering your HTML with a couple more nested elements purely for styling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flat sharp corner or beveled corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883963/flat-sharp-corner-or-beveled-corners)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no CSS rule to do it, but it is possible. You would need a `inline-block` or `block` element for your button, with a border on the left and right side. Then, you would need to place (with `absolute` positioning) two pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after` on the top and bottom part of the container. Simply add perspective and rotate the X value of the elements accordingly and you're good to go. It might not be "pixel perfect" on every device but it'll look damn near perfect on most recent devices and browsers.

You can have a look at these hexagonal buttons I made a little while ago to get a better idea: https://codepen.io/chriskirknielsen/pen/MpXKVV

EDIT: Here's a code snippet instead of a Codepen link:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .25s all .02s ease-in-out;
}

body, html {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: #123143;
  height: 100%;
}

.button--hexagon {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .5rem;
  line-height: .5rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #ffce00;
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  padding: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
}

.button--hexagon span {
  z-index: 20;
  position: relative;
}

.button--hexagon::before, .button--hexagon::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: inherit;
  border-style: inherit;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(18, 49, 67, 0.75);
}

.button--hexagon::before {
  border-width: 2px 2px 0 2px;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: perspective(0.5rem) rotateX(3deg);
}

.button--hexagon::after {
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: center top;
  transform: perspective(0.5rem) rotateX(-3deg);
}

.button--hexagon:hover {
  color: #123143;
  border-color: #ffce00;
}

.button--hexagon:hover::before,
.button--hexagon:hover::after {
  background: #ffce00;
}
```

```html
<button class="button--hexagon"><span>Some text</span></button>
```

Comment: Those are some sweet buttons!

Comment: thanks a lot for this solution, I managed to make it look exactly like I need!

Answer (score 0):

Not easily with CSS there is not. You could try to use CSS shapes to get a rough similarity - but as shapes, you wont be able to get it exact and you likely wont be able to put a proper stroke on it if that is your intention.

```
#octagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

#octagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 29px solid red;
    border-left: 29px solid #eee;
    border-right: 29px solid #eee;
    width: 42px;
    height: 0;
}

#octagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 29px solid red;
    border-left: 29px solid #eee;
    border-right: 29px solid #eee;
    width: 42px;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you do a working demo with a stack snippet? I'm curious to see this in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clip-path property in pure css

```
button {
        width: 200px;
        min-height: 50px;
        clip-path: polygon(6% 0, 93% 0, 100% 22%, 100% 78%, 94% 98%, 7% 98%, 0 79%, 0 21%);
        background: green;
      }
```

and the button

```
  <button>Cut corner effect.</button>
```