# Skew borders in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am not really understanding the logic to create such type of borders. Can anyone please help me draw this border.

[image: Skew-bordered element]

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338078/3624336) in this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44338000/3624336).

Comment: Can you please give me in normal css not in scss. Thanks!

Comment: I have made an edit already to add plain ol' CSS. ;) The SCSS will make more sense in terms of values (perspective, etc.) so I recommend you read through that as well to full understand how this works.

Comment: Thanks!! This helped me a lot. Can you also help me draw this in SVG ?